# PI Testing for Spring batch applications

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, mutation-testing

I am trying to run Pi tests on one of my application of spring batch but after running it I am getting TIMED_OUT warnings saying Minion exited abnormally. So whether PI test supports spring batch applications or not ? Moreover I am getting warnings saying More threads at the end of tests.

P.S. I Tried different combinations of timeout constants too.

Comment: Hello GovindGx , what kind of Pi test you are conducting

Comment: Hello Ashish, Mutation tests to check the coverage and test cases using PITests.